# Solving a recurrence relation with two recursions

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion, recursive-algorithms, change-of-variable

I have the following function $r(n)$ where $n\in Z$ defined by:

$$
r(1) = 3
$$
$$
r(2) = 15 
$$
$$
r(n) = 5 \times r(\frac{n}{2}) - 4 \times r(\frac{n}{4})
$$

I am trying to turn that into a **non-recursive expression**.

**Change of variable ($n\rightarrow 2^m$)**

$
R(m) = r(n)
$

$
R(m) = 5R(m-1) - 4R(m-2) 
$

**Change of function:**

$
R(m) = 5^m h(m)
$

$
\implies 5^m h(m) = 5\times5^{m-1} h(m-1) - 4\times5^{m-2}h(m-2)
$

*Then dividing by $5^m$*

$
\implies h(m) = h(m-1) - \frac{1}{25}h(m-2)
$

This is where I am stuck - how can I finish this to get a non-recursive form of this algorithm? Did I do something wrong or miss something?

Comment: As written, your function is only defined where $n$ is a power of $2$. Is this intentional?

Comment: In any case, with the substitution $m = \log_2 n$, $r$ becomes a linear recurrence, which can be solved with a completely standard method described here: (https://brilliant.org/wiki/linear-recurrence-relations/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a [linear difference equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_difference_equation), and as described in the given link, we just notice the following:

$$R(m+2)=5R(m+1)-4R(m)$$

$$R^2=5R-4\implies R_+=4,R_-=1$$

Thus,

$$R(m)=a4^m+b$$

Plug $m=0,1$ to then find $a,b$, which finally give

$$R(m)=4^{m+1}-1$$

Comment: Could you elaborate on why $R(m) = a4^m + b$?

Comment: @Cobbles Because the solution must be of the form$$R(m)=a(R_+)^n+b(R_-)^n$$by the first link.

Answer (score 2):

> $R(m) = 5R(m-1) - 4R(m-2)$

At this point you got a linear recurrence, which can be solved the standard way using its characteristic polynomial, as noted already. For an alternative approach, write the recurrence as:

$$
R(m)-R(m-1)=4\big(R(m-1)-R(m-2)\big)
$$

With $\,S(m)=R(m)-R(m-1)\,$ the above telescopes to:

$$
S(m)=4 \cdot S(m-1) = 4^2 \cdot S(m-2) = \cdots = 4^{m-1} \cdot S(1)
$$

Since $\,S(1) = R(1)-R(0) = r(2)-r(1)=15-3=12\,$, this gives:

$$
R(m)-R(m-1) = S(m) = 4^{m-1} \cdot 12 = 3 \cdot 4^{m}
$$

Adding the equalities up, and telescoping again:

$$\require{cancel}
R(m)-R(0) = 3\cdot\left(4^{m}+4^{m-1}+\cdots+4^2+4\right) = \cancel{3} \cdot 4 \cdot \frac{4^m-1}{\cancel{4-1}} = 4^{m+1} - 4
$$

So in the end $R(m) = R(0) +4^{m+1} - 4=r(1) +4^{m+1} - 4=3 +4^{m+1} - 4=4^{m+1}-1\,$.

Comment: Thanks, but what happened to the 5 and the 4 coefficient before the $R(m-1)$ and $R(m-2)$?

Comment: @Cobbles The $5$ got split into a $4+1$ here: $R(m)-R(m-1)=4 R(m-1) - 4 R(m-2)\,$.